# Flutter - center button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout

I'm creating a UI with 5 buttons. One of them should be center and its width should be 50% of the screen. The height should be the same size (it should be a circle). I tried with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` but it doesn't work.

This is the closest I got:
[image]

The code is:

```
Widget _playButton() {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      widthFactor: 0.5,
      heightFactor: 0.5, // I know this is wrong
      child: Container(
        alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
        color: Colors.red,
        /*decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: hexToColor('#E8532E'),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),*/
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "PLAY",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The container where I have this button:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: <Widget>[_myScreenOptions(), _playButton()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Obviously, the rest of the buttons should be clickable.

Comment: Is the question, how to make it a circle or how to know the radius?

Comment: can you please share any image what exactly you want? and _myScreenOptions() code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna create a circular button, you don't have to worry about width & height, giving only one size is enough... or you can use *FractionallySizedBox*, as you already did.

**Code output:**

[image: demo output code]

**Sample code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleCenterButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _myScreenOptions(),
            _playButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _playButton() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Play game");
      },
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.5,
        child: Container(
          // defining one dimension works as well, as Flutter knows how to render a circle.
//        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "PLAY",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _myScreenOptions() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        buildRow([
          buildOption(Color(0xff1D4554), Icons.person, "Teams"),
          buildOption(Color(0xff229B8D), Icons.folder_open, "Pets"),
        ]),
        buildRow([
          buildOption(Color(0xffE7C16A), Icons.videogame_asset, "Modes"),
          buildOption(Color(0xffF2A061), Icons.settings, "Options"),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildOption(Color bgColor, IconData iconData, String title) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: bgColor,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              iconData,
              size: 80,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildRow(List<Widget> buttons) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: buttons,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure Daniel. Please accept my answer as valid if it helped you.